# How to assign a vector of values to a vertex label in igraph in R?

Tags: r, igraph, graph-algorithm

Suppose, I have a graph with 3 nodes and 3 edges in `igraph` like this:

```
library(igraph)
G <- graph(c(1,2,1,3,2,3),directed = FALSE)
V(G)$myLabel <- 1:3
```

and it works perfectly fine. But I would like to assign a label to each node with a different length. For example:

```
G <- graph(c(1,2,1,3,2,3),directed = FALSE)
V(G)[1]$myLabel <- c(10,20)
V(G)[2]$myLabel <- c(-1,-2,-3)
V(G)[3]$myLabel <- c(100,200,300,400)
```

And during my analysis of the graph, the length of labels of each node might change. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You must assign objects of length 1 to a node.
Otherwise, only the first element will be taken.
However, you can use `list` to encapsulate vectors to fit that requirement:

```r
library(igraph)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'igraph'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     decompose, spectrum
#> The following object is masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     union

G <- graph(c(1,2,1,3,2,3),directed = FALSE)

V(G)[1]$myLabel <- list(c(10,20))
V(G)[2]$myLabel <- list(c(-1,-2,-3))
V(G)[3]$myLabel <- list(c(100,200,300,400))

V(G)[1]$myLabel
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 10 20
V(G)[2]$myLabel
#> [[1]]
#> [1] -1 -2 -3
V(G)[3]$myLabel
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 100 200 300 400

# adding a new label to one node
V(G)[3]$myLabel <- list(c(V(G)[3]$myLabel[[1]], 500))
V(G)[3]$myLabel
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 100 200 300 400 500
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you! this works, but after initialization like the above, if I change right now V(G)[3]$myLabel <- 1:10 then it does not work.

Comment: You need the list: `V(G)[3]$myLabel <- list(1:10)`